# Not able to drag Flow Player around

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using flow player in my website as a control, I am not able to drag the player when the video is being played.

Kindly help me with this.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: As you've tagged this jquery-ui, I'm assuming you're using the draggable module, correct? do you have some sample code to post? It's possible that you aren't binding the draggable event to the right element, but without seeing your code it's difficult to tell.